# Different formula depending on if it's odd or even

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a code in Haskell that does n^k = (n * n)^(k/2) when k is even, and n^k = n * (n^(k−1)) if k is odd. 
I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
power2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
power2 n 0 = 1
power2 n k
   | k < 0 = error "negative argument"
   | k `mod` 2 == 0 = even            -- Am I supposed to write  = even here?
   | otherwise = odd
if k even = (n 2) ( div k 2)       -- (n^2)^(k/2)  ???
if k odd = n * (n) (k-1))          -- Is this n^(k-1) ???
```

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#line-489

Comment: `if k even` and likewise `if k odd` does not make sense and will not compile, i think you wanted `where even = ...`. Also GHCi will let you interactively work through errors while giving feedback. Use it to test your comments.

Comment: These days, we have a better type than `Integer` for the exponent. Import `Numeric. Natural` and use `power2 :: Integer -> Natural -> Integer`. Then you don't have to worry about the exponent being negative, because it *can't* be.

Comment: `Numeric.Natural` just hides the runtime error; `power2 3 (-5)` would still typecheck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`even` and `odd` are functions in Haskell and you may use them directly inside guards conditions to test if a number is even/odd.

Below is one option:

```
power2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
power2 n 0 = 1
power2 n k
   | k < 0  = error "negative argument"
   | even k = power2 (n * n) (div k 2)
   | odd  k = n * ( power2 n (k-1) )
```

http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/odd_f.html
http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/even_f.html

**EDIT:**

Of course you may write your own version of even/odd functions and use them as an alternative.

Example:

```
myEven :: Integer -> Bool
myEven n = n `mod` 2 == 0

myOdd :: Integer -> Bool
myOdd n = n `mod` 2 == 1

power2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
power2 n 0 = 1
power2 n k
   | k < 0  = error "negative argument"
   | myEven k = power2 (n * n) (div k 2)
   | myOdd  k = n * ( power2 n (k-1) )
```

Comment: Using `| ... = True | otherwise = False` is generally considered poor style. You have the truth value already: just use it! Similarly, you should flip them with `not` rather than guards. I've edited your answer to follow convention.

Comment: @dfeuer: I was trying to make the example more readable and understandable for newcomer. In real world scenario there would not be a need to substitute standard `even` and `odd` functions. Thanks for your opinion anyway.